# Use AndroidX Library without enabling AndroidX to true

Tags: android, androidx

I have a huge codebase which indeed will take a lot of time to shift to AndroidX support, now there is a library that I hugely depend on with which I need to integrate inside my android app.

I have tried several methods like changing the min SDK version but still, my app won't build until I enable AndroidX to true.

I was asking if there is a possibility of using the library which uses AndroidX without needing my app to support AndroidX?

Or what can I do in a scenario like this?

Comment: what is your target sdk

Comment: api level 25 is the one i  target